# Increasing space between lines on one side of bilingual text using reledpar?

Tags: reledpar

I'm working on a bilingual text in which one of the languages is significantly less verbose than the other. I'm using reledpar with advancedpshifts and it's all working beautifully. What I'm wondering is whether there's a way using reledpar (or some other package) to do a layout that looks like this?

[image]

That is, in which the spacing between lines is larger on one side of the page than the other, so that there's no chunk of space showing at the bottom of the page?

Comment: short answer: unfortuntaly, not possible yet. It is a in my todolist since many year. But no time.

Comment: @Maïeul Thanks for letting me know—it's such a wonderful package, I'm happy to wait for it to become more wonderful still!

Comment: maybe one day, but I can't say